# VBA to copy paste ranges based on not having 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of values in range L10:M34 and I'd like to select all L:M where M doesn't have value 0. Then I want to paste whole selection as values without blacks to U5. I am able to do that manually, but I'd like to use VBA, and repeat this to 2 other sets of locations in same worksheet.
What I have is only selecting whole range to copy, and I'd like to exclude rows where M has 0.

```
Range("L10:M34").Select   
    Selection.Copy
    Range("U5").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly :

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim dest As Range
Dim i As Long: Dim col As Long
Dim rgNonZero As Range: Dim r As Range

Set rg = Range("L10:M34")

i = Range(Split(rg.Address(0, 0), ":")(0)).Row
col = Range(Split(rg.Address(0, 0), ":")(1)).Column
Do Until Cells(i, col) <> 0: i = i + 1: Loop
Set rgNonZero = Range(Cells(i, col - 1), Cells(i, col))

For Each r In rg.Rows
    If r.Columns(2).Value <> 0 Then Set rgNonZero = Union(rgNonZero, r)
Next

rgNonZero.Copy
Range("U5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

First the sub create the data range in L10:M34 as rg variable.
Then get the first row defined in rg into i variable.
Then get the column (which has the zero and non zero values) number into col variable.
Then it loop (sorry difficult for me to explain in English) until it find the first row of column M which has value non-zero, then set the range of this row as rgNonZero variable.

Then it loop each row in rg as r variable, and check if this row column(2) value is not zero - then it add the range of r into rgNonZero.

After the loop done, it copy rgNonZero and paste tranpose to cell U5.